# Use ssh2_exec() to extract a tar file in the "/" directory of a remote server

Tags: php, command, extract, tar, ssh2-exec

Am trying to extract a .tar file in the "/" directory of a remote server (server2), using the ssh2_exec() function from a php file located in another server (server1).

php file in server1:

```
<?php
$p_main_ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'; // ip of the server2
$user = 'root';
$p_password = 'password'; // server2 root password
   $connection = ssh2_connect($p_main_ip, 22);
   if($connection)
   {
      if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $p_password))
      {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'tar xvpfz /home/t.tgz -C /');
      }
   }
?>
```

PS : I was able to extract the file in "/home" directory using this:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'tar xvpfz /home/t.tgz -C /home');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to extract it there?

Comment: Because it s a backup of the server, and it contains all files and installed packages, and it was made for the whole server.

Comment: That wont work on a running system / mounted drive.

Comment: I gave up using that extension and moved over to `PHPseclib`.  https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib  it's so much better.  Just make sure to get the 2.0 version. However the Documentation sucks.

Comment: I never heard of it, i'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Thank you.

Comment: PHPseclib wont help with this issue.

Comment: So there is no way i could remotely extract a .tgz file in "/" ?

Comment: It depends whats in the backup, so if its got `/proc`  `/mnt` etc it wont work, have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR